# How much energy does the most powerful supernova release in any form other than neutrinos?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, space, supernova, explosions

I have read most of the supernova article on wikipedia, and there are a lot of numbers and different types of supernovae so I am confused.

What I need to know is how much energy is released from some very powerful supernovae in any form (EM radiation, kinetic energy.. etc) other than neutrinos.

Also please take a look at [this](http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=VlfSviM9eIIC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=1052%20supernova%20ergs%20kinetic%20energy&source=bl&ots=JqgIQVqkf4&sig=C-5E6HEkVCvRjCDlIrcDvw_cgwE&hl=ar&sa=X&ei=zBLPUoflHrGp0AX724DIBQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=1052%20supernova%20ergs%20kinetic%20energy&f=false) and tell me what you think about this 10^52 ergs of kinetic energy.

Comment: All types of SNe kick off $10^{51}$ ergs = $10^{44}$ Joules in kinetic energy.

Comment: Yes, but that is the very normal of any type. I think pair-instability supernova release much more, but I've no idea if the percentage of the energy released as neutrinos in such event is known.

Comment: Since the precursors to PISN are an order of magnitude larger than the CCSN (100 $M_\odot$ vs 25 $M_\odot$), it's an order of magnitude difference in the energy. That is, $10^{52}$ ergs.

Comment: In regards to the paper: I pretty much implicitly trust anything that has [Stan Woosley's](http://www.ucolick.org/~board/faculty/woosley.html) name attached to it; if his 1999 paper says that SN1998bw had $E\sim10^{52}$ ergs, it is correct.

Comment: So is it possible for a supernova to have kinetic energy of say 5*10^51 erg if it is the result of a star a couple of times more massive than the one which results in 10^51 erg of KE ?

Comment: At least in regards to CCSN, there are several factors that determine the explosion energy: initial mass, remnant mass, & metallicity to name a few. A factor of a few, like 5, is well within observational evidence for explosion energies (these are typically given in ranges anyway).